# Can´t re-render a Google Maps with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, maps

I´m trying to re-render a google map based on a location(city). I enter the city in the input type, but nothing happens. Can anyone help me with this? I already tried a lot of things, but nothing happens. Regards,

https://pastebin.pl/view/e31aeb6a
[enter link description here][1]

Comment: Can you add an [sscce]http://sscce.org/ of your code in your question? You can use [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/).

Comment: Yes, here: https://93p4y.csb.app/

Comment: Can you explain further your use case? As I understand, you are typing the city name in the input and it should show in the map. Is this correct? Do you also want to put a Marker of that place on the map?

Comment: Exactly! No need to put the marker, just re-render the map clicking the button. I´m in trouble handling the google maps API key too. I need some free map to put there.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for something like [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/geocoding-simple) where you will use Geocoding API to Geocode the address from your input then once geocoded, it will get the coordinates and plot it to your map using Maps JavaScript API.

You might also, would like to check [Places Autocomplete with Maps JavaScript API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-autocomplete) where it provides suggestion on the address you are searching for then renders the place you selected on the map.

Please note that if you want to use Google Maps API, you need to [use an API key](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key) and usage of these APIs are [billed accordingly](https://developers.google.com/maps/billing/gmp-billing).

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/geocoding-app-lsfgkk?file=index.js) is how I implemented it on React. Code snippet below:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './style.css';

var map;
const API_KEY = "PUT_API_KEY_HERE";
class GeocodingApp extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.renderMap = this.renderMap.bind(this);
    this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      input: ""
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {

       if (!window.google) {
            const script = document.createElement('script');
            script.type = 'text/javascript';
            script.src = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=` + API_KEY + `&libraries=geometry,places`;
            script.id = 'googleMaps';
            script.async = true;
            script.defer = true;
            document.body.appendChild(script);
            script.addEventListener('load', e => {
                this.renderMap()
            })
        } else {
            this.renderMap()
        }
    
  }

  renderMap() {
    const coords = { lat: 41.375885, lng: 2.177813 };
    const el = document.getElementById("map");

    if (el) {
      map = new google.maps.Map(el, {
        zoom: 16,
        center: {
          lat: coords.lat,
          lng: coords.lng
        }
      });

      return map;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }

  handleInputChange(event) {
    const target = event.target;
    const value = target.type === "checkbox" ? target.checked : target.value;
    const name = target.name;

    this.setState({
      [name]: value
    });
  }

  handleClick(event) {
    const geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    this.codeAddress(geocoder);
    event.preventDefault();
  }

 
//Handles Geocoding part
  codeAddress(geocoder) {
    var address = this.state.input;
    geocoder.geocode({ address: address }, function(results, status) {
      if (status === "OK") {
        //'results[0].geometry.location' is the coordinates of the address you want to find
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
      } else {
        return null;
      }
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div >
        <h1>ADD YOUR API KEY TO MAKE IT WORKIN</h1>
        <input
          id="input"
          name="input"
          value={this.state.input}
          onChange={this.handleInputChange}
        />
        <button id="submit" onClick={this.handleClick}>
          {" "}
          Search
        </button>
        <div id="map"  />
        
      </div>
    );
  }
}

 ReactDOM.render(<GeocodingApp />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

Comment: I can´t compile:
Line 43:17:  'google' is not defined  no-undef
Line 68:26:  'google' is not defined  no-undef

Comment: It seems that the [sample code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/geocoding-app-lsfgkk?file=index.js)  I provided does not have that issue.